# Sintaxe Inválida no Python, o que está errado ou faltando?

Tags: python, sintaxe

```
print('{:=^40}'.format(' SIMULADOR DE JUROS COMPOSTOS '))
print(''' ESCOLHA A OPÇÃO
[1] Para Juros
[2] Para Capital
[3] Para Taxa
[4] Para Tempo''')
opção = int(input('Qual a sua opção? '))
if opção == 1:
    capital = float(input('Entre com o capital '))
    taxa = float(input('Entre com a taxa '))
    tempo = float(input('Entre com o tempo ' ))
    print('O valor do Juros é: ',capital*(((1+(taxa/100))**tempo)-1))
elif opção == 2:
    juros = float(input('Entre com o Juros '))
    taxa = float(input('Entre com a taxa '))
    tempo = float(input('Entre com o tempo ' ))
    print('O valor do Capital é: ',juros/(((1+(taxa/100)**tempo)-1)
elif opção == 3:
    capital= float(input('Entre com o capital '))
    juros = float(input('Entre com o Juros '))
    tempo = float(input('Entre com o tempo ' ))
    print('O valor da Taxa é: ',(((capital+juros)/capital)**(1/tempo))-1)
elif opção == 4:
    juros = float(input('Entre com o Juros '))
    capital= float(input('Entre com o capital '))
    taxa = float(input('Entre com a taxa '))
    print('O valor do Tempo é: ',(ln((capital+juros)/capital))/(ln(1+(taxa/100))
else:
    print ('Opção inválida. Tente novamente')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Geralmente, quando ocorre este erro de `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` em sintaxe corretas você deve olhar para linha anterior, indicando que talvez você esqueceu de fechar algum colchete ou parênteses.

Foi exatamente isto que aconteceu no seu código, observe esta parte:

```
print('O valor do Capital é: ',juros/(((1+(taxa/100)**tempo)-1)
elif opção == 3:
```

> Você 'abriu' com 5 parênteses, porém 'fechou' somente  com 3
>   parênteses.

Esta outra parte do código:

```
 print('O valor do Tempo é: ',(ln((capital+juros)/capital))/(ln(1+(taxa/100))
else:
```

> Você 'abriu' 7 parênteses, entretanto 'fechou' erroneamente com 5
>   parênteses.

Seu código ficará assim:

```
print('{:=^40}'.format(' SIMULADOR DE JUROS COMPOSTOS '))
print(''' ESCOLHA A OPÇÃO
[1] Para Juros
[2] Para Capital
[3] Para Taxa
[4] Para Tempo''')
opção = int(input('Qual a sua opção? '))
if opção == 1:
     capital = float(input('Entre com o capital '))
     taxa = float(input('Entre com a taxa '))
     tempo = float(input('Entre com o tempo ' ))
     print('O valor do Juros é: ',capital*(((1+(taxa/100))**tempo)-1))
elif opção == 2:
    juros = float(input('Entre com o Juros '))
    taxa = float(input('Entre com a taxa '))
    tempo = float(input('Entre com o tempo ' ))
    print('O valor do Capital é: ',juros/(((1+(taxa/100)**tempo)-1)))
elif opção == 3:
    capital= float(input('Entre com o capital '))
    juros = float(input('Entre com o Juros '))
    tempo = float(input('Entre com o tempo ' ))
    print('O valor da Taxa é: ',(((capital+juros)/capital)**(1/tempo))-1)
elif opção==4:
    juros = float(input('Entre com o Juros '))
    capital= float(input('Entre com o capital '))
    taxa = float(input('Entre com a taxa '))

    print('o valor o tempo é: ',(ln((capital+juros)/capital))/(ln(1+(taxa/100))))
else:
    print ('Opção inválida. Tente novamente')
```